# Is there a script or an add-on that can override ALL tumblr themes to something simple?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am annoyed by the complexity of tumblr. themes, especially those that remind me of furniture stores and take ages to load. I want to browse, not to get lost, go back to the front page each time and read stuff stuck to the right side of the screen, written in a tiny wee so-2002 font. Is there a way to make them all look super-simple, e.g. with a title, a simple column and pagination? Not as simple as in the mobile app (I hate endless scrolling), but somewhat close.

Thanks for any possible idea!

Comment: This is not a question for stack overflow as this has nothing to do with software development.

Comment: You can use [this website](http://noneblr.com).

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I had a brain fart.